# Вернуть все буквы алфавита?

Tags: python

Не получается вернуть все буквы алфавита с помощью метода `eng_letters()`. Возвращает только букву `"А"`. Подскажите, что я упускаю

```py
class Alphabet:
    def __init__(self, lang):
        self.lang = lang
    """Возвращаем язык"""
    def which_lang(self):
        return self.lang

    """Английские буквы"""  
    def eng_letters(self):
        list = ' '
        for i in range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1):
            list+=chr(i)
            return list  

a = Alphabet("eng")
print(a.eng_letters())
```

Comment: return на один индент влево

Comment: Не надо называть переменную встроенным именем list. Тем более, это не имя никак не отражает её содержимое.

Comment: Все было на столько очевидно, спасибо splash58)

Comment: Хорошо, поменяю название)

Answer (score 2):

В принципе вам дали пояснение по подводу вашей ошибки. Сдвинуть `return list` влево. Ваш код заходит в `for`, делает одну итерацию, по окончанию, которой вы вызываете `return`.

Я бы хотел еще обратить внимание на то, что результат вы конкатенируете строку. Строка - не изменяемый тип данных, поэтому при данном использовании вы каждый раз создаете новый объект. Это значит, что построение последовательности будет занимать квадратичную стоимость по времени выполнения в общей длине последовательности.

Есть несколько способов избежать этого и один из - это собрать результат в список, а затем использовать метод `join()`.

```py
def eng_letters(self):
    list_ = []
    for i in range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1):
        list_.append(chr(i))
    return ''.join(list_)
```

Более подробную информацию можно найти в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range), подраздел `Notes` -> 6 пункт (англ.)

Если вы хотите использовать зарезервированное слово, как свою переменную, то хорошим тоном будет добавить нижнее подчеркивание после имени переменной `list_, dict_, str_` и так далее.

В комментариях возникли сомнения по поводу выводов из документации, относительно времени исполнения, указанные мной в ответе. Прикладываю код для тестирования, чтобы можно было проверить, и результаты на моей машине. Последовательность увеличина до 10000 знаков, и сделаны по 1000 тестов на каждую функцию

```py
code1 = """
def eng_letters():
    list_ = []
    for i in range(10000):
        list_.append(chr(i))
    return ''.join(list_)
eng_letters()
"""

import timeit

print(timeit.timeit(code1, number=1000)/1000)

code2 = """
def eng_letters1():
    list_ = ""
    for i in range(10000):
        list_ += (chr(i))
    return list_
eng_letters1()
"""
print(timeit.timeit(code2, number=1000)/1000)
```

Результаты

```
0.0015904509999999999
0.0022290120000000003

0.0014631717
0.0024775018000000003

0.0014995999999999998
0.002166277

0.001480243
0.00212604
```

Результат с оригинальными последовательностями

```
3.012499999999998e-06     # list
3.1453000000000036e-06    # string

2.8779999999999985e-06    # list
2.9080000000000008e-06    # string

2.581899999999998e-06     # list
3.1011000000000024e-06    # string
```

Значения очень малы, но даже здесь подтвержден тезис из документации.

А если отказаться от `for` и использовать `list comprehension`, результаты в скорости выполнения будут еще более хороши

```py
def eng_letters2():
    list_ = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1)]
    return ''.join(list_)
```

Результат времени c оригинальной последовательностью, будет отличаться в лучшую сторону

```
2.4053000000003876e-06
```

А с 10000 знаков, как в тестовом скрипте, результат

```py
code3 = """
def eng_letters2():
    list_ = [chr(i) for i in range(10000)]
    return ''.join(list_)
eng_letters2()
"""

print(timeit.timeit(code3, number=1000)/1000)

# OUT
# 0.001160491
```

Comment: тест показывает, что решение с append работает чуть дольше чем конкатенация: 7.97 µs ± 82 ns per loop против 6.89 µs ± 126 ns per loop

Comment: @SergFSM не ко мне эти данные. К разработчикам. В прошлый раз я подписался и игрался с тестами, а итог оказался предсказуем и описан в документации.

Comment: @SergFSM больно вы меня задеваете и заставляете сомневаться в прочитанной документации. Поскольку мне неизвестна ваша методология тестирования, я тестировал по своему. Модуль `timeit`, для уменьшения внешнего влияния и усреднения показателей из выборки, были проведены по 100 тестов и масштабирована последовательность до 10000 знаков. Результат со строкой: 0.0022290120000000003. Результат со списком: 0.0015904509999999999. Опровергните эти результаты?

Comment: я привел тест работы коды из данной конкретной задачи с указанными в ней параметрами, разумеется, с другими данными и результат может быть другой.

Comment: @SergFSM так поэтому и нужны объективные данные, а не просто "Вот мои результаты тестов и они опровергают написанное в ответе". Я сейчас приложу еще и результат с теми последовательностями, которые указаны изначально в вопросе.

Comment: @SergFSM если вы сможете опровергнуть мои изыскания, то я выберу ваш лучший ответ, объявлю по  вопросу конкурс и назначу вознаграждение за ваш ответ 500. Если нет, удалите ваш комментарий, он вводит в заблуждение. И я свои комментарии тоже удалю.

Comment: @Dmitry В теории вы правы, а на практике я попробовал разные варианты, везде почему-то конкатенация выигрывает, даже на очень больших размерах строк и списков. Непонятно, в чём тут дело. Возможно, в последних версиях Питона сделана какая-то оптимизация на эту тему.

Comment: @Dmitry Так то конечно списку тоже нужно периодически расширяться, но в теории это должно происходить быстрее, потому что он должен расширяться не каждый раз при добавлении, а новая строка создаётся каждый раз при конкатенации. Это нужно глубоко в общем копать.

Comment: @CrazyElf на ваш экспернтый взгляд, вы бы что применяли? Не задумываясь

Comment: @Dmitry Я бы применял список, потому что считается, что конкатенация это плохо и про это везде написано ))  Ну и вообще раздельные сущности лучше раздельно и хранить, а объединять в последний момент в другую сущность. Как-то так.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Alphabet:
    def __init__(self, lang):
        self.lang = lang
    # Возвращаем язык

    def which_lang(self):
        return self.lang

    # Английские буквы

    def eng_letters(self):
        list_ = ''
        for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1):
            list_ += chr(i)
        return list_


a = Alphabet('eng')
print(a.eng_letters())
```

Во-первых, старайтесь всегда писать код по правилам `PEP-8`.
Во-вторых, нельзя называть переменные ключевыми словами, ставьте подчеркивание, например `list_`.
В-третьих, `return` нужно сместить на один TAB влево.